# Is this a PyCharm 2017.2.2 refactoring limitation, or a coding error?

Tags: python, refactoring, pycharm, automated-refactoring

I'm a fan of JetBrains IntelliJ, and now am enjoying the support PyCharm offers for Python. But I'm having trouble trying to refactor some python code correctly with PyCharm 2017.2.2. I can demonstrate the problem with two cases, where the first one works but the second one doesn't.

Working snippet:

```
import pandas as pd

def main():
    c = 2
    a = pd.Series([1,2,3])
    b = a.apply(lambda x:
        x+1
    )
    print (b)

main()
```

I can select the three lines

```
    b = a.apply(lambda x:
        x+1
    )
```

When I refactor > extract > method, I'm offered a dialog box suggesting `a` as a parameter, and b as the return value. When I accept, the result is:

```
import pandas as pd

def main():
    c = 2
    a = pd.Series([1,2,3])
    b = method_name(a)
    print (b)


def method_name(a):
    b = a.apply(lambda x:
                x + 1
                )
    return b


main()
```

Now, I make a change. Instead of `x+1` inside the lambda, I use `x+c`. I would expect that `c` would then be identified as a parameter for the new function, but it isn't. As a result, I end up with this code, which doesn't work:

```
import pandas as pd

def main():
    c = 2
    a = pd.Series([1,2,3])
    b = method_name(a)
    print (b)


def method_name(a):
    b = a.apply(lambda x:
                x + c
                )
    return b


main()
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: 'limitation' might be a more useful term; it is also less combative.

Comment: Please file an issue here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, @user2235698. I attached this to issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23499

Answer (score 0):

Your only passing one value to method_name so c represents nothing.

Comment: Yes, that is the reason that this code doesn't work. But PyCharm produced this code through the "refactoring extract method" operation. By definition, refactoring shouldn't change the behavior of the code. Here, the behavior did change. Is there something I can do to help make the PyCharm refactoring succeed?

Comment: I never use pycharms refactoring feature. I prefer to write the code myself.